# Declaring a Boost C++ Matrix causes a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, boost, matrix, segmentation-fault, numeric

This one line:

```
boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> prices (vec.size() - 1, vec[0].size() - 1);
```

keeps causing a segmentation fault while debugging.  I don't understand why, because up to this point in the code, it is identical another program which already works.  I also tried declaring matrix the following ways (different runs):

```
boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> prices;  
boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> prices(1, 1);
```

but it still happens!  WTH!!  This happens both in Eclipse CDT and QtCreator.

**EDIT:**
vec is a 2 dimensional string vector:

```
vector< vector<string> > etf_prices`;
```

Comment: Please show the definition and initialization for `vec`. Also, you declare two matrices with the same name in the second example.

Comment: No I meant, I tried to just declare the matrix three different way (in 3 different runs) and got a segmentation fault error regardless if I was using vec or not.

Comment: Here is [an example](http://ideone.com/lyrmU) that works fine. My only guess was that `vec` did not contain anything. However, you will have to show more code probably.

Comment: @GManNickG Segmentation fault on run, when debugging the fault triggers at that line.

Comment: @JesseGood I've tried declaring the matrix without any parameters as well as with size (1, 1).  Each time I keep getting a segmentation error.

Comment: Just before the line that crashes, check the values of `vec.size()-1` and `vec[0].size()-1` using `printf` or `cout`. Make sure that they are both >=0 and less than `prices.size1()` and `prices.size2()`, respectively.